# Es gehört dazu allerdings

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

I have two problems that I need help with these sentences:

> Es **gehört dazu** allerdings, dass man sich nicht durch übertriebenes Nationalgefühl blenden lässt, **wie** es bei einem großen Teil der Franzosen und Deutschen der Fall ist.

I find it a bit difficult to understand "gehört" and "dazu". Gehören usually means "belong to", to be "a part of". But what does it mean by "dazu" here? Gehören zu is usually used, which means belong to.

The second thing I need help is the relative pronoun "wie". The second half of the sentence, "wie...Fall ist" seems to me to be equivalent to "as it is the case with".

Why do you need a relative pronoun "wie" here.

I know when learning a new language, you shouldn't try to translate them into your familiar language like English. But I am a newcomer so many of these points are a bit difficult for me to absorb.

Would appreciate it if you can help.

Comment: Why do you need the 'as' in 'as is the case? Same thing with 'wie' in German.

Comment: Fixed the original sentence, so as not to confuse other learners. 

To your first point: "Dazu gehören" can not only mean "belong to" in the strict sense, but also "being required or necessary, in order to be proper, or fulfill expectations or  meet conditions." It refers back to the previous sentence or thought: In order to [whatever] it is necessary to not letting oneself be blinded by nationalism etc, as is the case with a large part of French and Germans … (Sorry for the literal translation).

Answer (score 2):

First of all the sentence should read

> Es gehört dazu allerdings, dass man sich nicht durch übertriebenes **N**ationalgef**ü**hl blenden l**ä**sst, wie es bei einem großen **T**eil der Franzosen und Deutschen der Fall ist.

Note, that German is case-sensitive. It's important to observe the use of capital or small initial letters since the meaning could change drastically.
Also: ä, ü and ö are not just funny looking versions of a, u and o but different letters.

Now to your question:

As you state yourself

> *Gehören* usually means "belong to", to be "a part of".

Now - *blong to **what***?
*A part of **what***?

That's something that was said before your actual quote.

> *Zu* [whatever was said before] *gehört auch* ...

Since the part in braces was already mentioned, the *dazu* is used to refer back to *[whatever was said before]*.

> *Dazu* gehört auch ...

---

As @planetmaker has already indicated in a comment:

You are right -

> wie es bei ... der Fall ist

is equivalent to

> as it is the case with ...

and just like you use *as* in English here you use *wie* in German. So there is nothing special about that.

Comment: Sorry, I had already fixed the errors you mentioned …

Comment: @Ingmar No problem at all! ;)